# Consume a soap web service with SSIS

Tags: soap, ssis

Can anyone tell me what the easiest way of consuming a web service would be using SSIS, where there are complex types in the WSDL that cause errors so you can't use the SSIS web service task? I previously came up with a way to do it using an SSIS script task, which generated a cURL command and that's worked very well until now. 
For some reason, I can't get cURL to work with a new service that I have to consume. All I need to do is submit a soap request using a method described in the service's wsdl, and download the soap response as an XML file to my local server. 
I guess there would be a million ways of answering this question, but hopefully someone can suggest what might be the easiest way to do the soap requests within SSIS.

Comment: Call an external script or console command that does the download of the XML file for you?

Comment: Yes that's it, in a nutshell. As I said above, I've been using cURL until now, but can't get it to work with this particular service. Can u suggest something else other than cURL?

Comment: Or maybe someone can help me to get it to work with cURL?

Comment: Oh sorry, now I realise what cURL does. So what's the error message when you use cURL? Maybe you can use a different tool like this: http://www.soapui.org/Test-Automation/functional-tests.html and see if you get any more error messages?

Comment: Thanks, although I tried it before, I looked at soapui again following your message. I can get it to generate a text report, but I'm using the free version so the bottom section of the Reports tab is greyed-out, so I can't change the format to XML. I guess I could find another way to read the text file (which contains the xml). I'll look at it further tomorrow. I'm not getting an error message from cURL (even using verbose). It's the target site's soap api that returns a generic message that just says it's unable to process my request and to contact their helpdesk (and they so far can't help)

Comment: Here are some examples of VBScript code that downloads a soap request: http://www.example-code.com/vbscript/http_soap.asp, http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/deed3efb-1e11-4e7e-8bfd-96a981de5c35. If you think this is the direction you want to go in I could help. But I guess you might just get the same error message. and here's one using powershell: http://www.iislogs.com/steveschofield/execute-a-soap-request-from-powershell

Comment: Fantastic links! The powershell one really did the trick quickly! That was exactly the kind of thing I was looking for. The others look great too and I'm definitely going to try them out too. Thanks so much :-)

Comment: I followed the Powershell link and at the bottom there was another link to the newer Powershell version 3, which was the one that I used - with the new Invoke-WebRequest command:  http://rambletech.wordpress.com/2011/09/21/posting-soap-request-from-windows-powershell/

Comment: ElectricLlama - You should paste those links as the answer, and maybe the new Powershell version above too, so that I can mark this question as answered by you, as I'd really like to give you credit for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some examples of VBScript code that downloads a soap request:

http://example-code.com/vbscript/http_soap.asp

http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/deed3efb-1e11-4e7e-8bfd-96a981de5c35

If you think this is the direction you want to go in I could help. But I guess you might just get the same error message. and here's one using powershell:

http://www.iislogs.com/steveschofield/execute-a-soap-request-from-powershell

Comment: Thanks again, and here's the link to the newer version of Powerpoint, which has the invoke-webRequest command. http://rambletech.wordpress.com/2011/09/21/posting-soap-request-from-windows-powershell/

Comment: Glad I could help - sorry it's just a bunch of links not a real solution but all good. Perhaps if you establish a solution you could post an update with your final issue - why cURL doesn't work but some other tool does.